# Google Map in iPhone5 simulator

Tags: iphone, google-maps, touch, sencha-touch-2

I am facing an issue with google map .. I am using Xcode 4.5 with cordova lib .. I have develop an app its working fine .. But i have an issue with google map i.e. it also works well in google chrome, safari but it does not works in iPhone5 simulator.. Take a look to code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
Layout:'fit',// also tried vbox,card,hbox
{
xtype:'map',
useCurrentLocation:true,
},
```

Kindly tell me whats wrong if anyone knows.

Comment: i don't think so .. Just this msg shown on the screen that google map API required and nothing else it is working fine in google chrome

Comment: Probably because the Google Map API is not loaded when your app try to display the map.

Comment: Could you add to your post you index.html file